# Inserting documents in MongoDB using PyMongo in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, nosql, pymongo

I am inserting documents in MongoDB using the PyMongo library in Python. The pandas dataframe has 37 fields and 60k records (link to dataset: https://drive.google.com/open?id=119T4uhvHc7CAwJgZRselWXpstAQhkj90). All fields in the dataframe have been converted to `str` type. I am getting the following error:

```
OverflowError: MongoDB can only handle up to 8-byte ints
```

The error still persists when I insert chunks of 2500 documents using a for loop.

Code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client['patenting_in_psi']
collection = db['sample5']

df=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\mazin\1-601.xlsx")

collection.insert_many((df.to_dict('records')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Some fields with missing data need to be normalized before converting the dataframe to a dictionary.

Values for `DWPIAccessionNumber` have to be normalized. For example, in record number `2524` is a 64-bit integer whose value is `20100000000000001078890512051682672902079220850980264522702989250781417512482524046970942628331980756243236345447307144055181790035144112662138043858072629370129477827567049201927634798584141270252235498775249725404749823022689297835494826055102466304887343437187655164225642338109880434082104977849399115776`.
This may be converted to a `bson.int64.Int64` type or conveniently typed as `str` (*there are instances where this value is a `str` - see record number 23 or a `nan`.*)

```
df['DWPIAccessionNumber'] = df['DWPIAccessionNumber'].astype(str)
```

Also `PublicationDate` field needs to be normalized as well.
For example, in record number `24696` its value is missing. You either drop the field, set some date or fill it a zero.

```
df['PublicationDate'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Now, your data is ready to be converted to a dictionary then inserted.